# find the even value li from a DOM in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

i have a dom like

```
<div class="first">
    <ol>
      <li>E</li>
      <li>F</li><!--Red Background-->
      <li>G</li>
      <li>H</li><!--Red Background-->
      <li>E</li>
      <li>F</li><!--Red Background-->
      <li>G</li>
      <li>H</li><!--Red Background-->
      <li>E</li>
      <li>F</li><!--Red Background-->
      <li>G</li>
      <li>H</li><!--Red Background-->
    </ol>
</div>
```

and i have select the even number of li, means the second , fourth ...

So i write like that

```
  var count = jQuery(".first ol li").size();
  for (var i=1; i<=count; i++ ){
    if(i%2 == 0){
      console.log(i);
      jQuery(".first ol:last li:nth-child(2) ").css("background", "red");
    }
  }
```

but it give some error . it can be selected. how can it selected plz help

Comment: *"it give some error"* Asking Technical Questions 101: ***What error?***

Comment: Note that unless you have to support IE8 and earlier, you can do this with CSS: `.first ol li:nth-child(even) { background-color: red; }`, [example](http://jsbin.com/ubotiw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the nth-child vvalue to be a formula. Instead of 2 put 2n:

```
jQuery(".first ol:last li:nth-child(2n) ").css("background", "red");
```

Comment: This also works:  jQuery(".first ol:last li:odd ").css("background", "red");

Answer (score 4):

```
var evenLis = $(".first li:odd");
```

**Yes, I really mean [`:odd`](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/)!** Since elements are `0` indexed, `2`, `4` etc. are odd numbers.

If you care about performance it can be quicker to use `filter`:

```
var evenLis = $(".first li").filter(":odd");
```

Why is this faster? The jQuery docs make that clear:

> Because :odd is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :odd cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. To achieve the best performance when using :odd to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>   use .filter(":odd").

Comment: Because `:odd` is not part of the CSS specification it would have to invoke Sizzle (rather than using `querySelectorAll`). I've copied the relevant part from the docs into the answer.

Comment: *"Yes, I really mean `:odd`"* Better yet, use the [actual CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) (`nth-child(even)`) rather than the Sizzle-specific `:odd`. That way if jQuery can defer to `querySelectorAll`, it will. (And it's `even` with the actual CSS selector because CSS, unlike jQuery, starts with 1.)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do this?

```
jQuery(".first ol li:nth-child(even)".css("background", "red");
```

Comment: +1 for using the actual CSS selector, so jQuery doesn't have to do the work if `querySelectorAll` can.

Answer (score 1):

Just `:odd`...

```
jQuery(".first ol:last :odd").css("background", "red");
```

Maybe the `ol:last` is redunadnt as well. dependes on your DOM